# Use Vuex in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I was able to fetch data and display them using Nuxt's Fetch API, but I want to utilize Vuex instead.

*store/index.js:*

```js
import Axios from 'axios'

export const getters = {
  isAuthenticated (state) {
    return state.auth.loggedIn
  },

  loggedInUser (state) {
    return state.auth.user
  }
}
export const state = () => ({
  videos: []
})

export const mutations = {
  storeVideos (state, videos) {
    state.videos = videos
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async getVideos (commit) {
    const res = await Axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${process.env.API_SECRET}&page=${this.currentPage}`)
    commit('storeVideos', res.data)
  }
}
```

*pages/test.vue:*

```html
    <template>
          <Moviecards
            v-for="(movie, index) in $store.state.videos"
            :key="index"
            :movie="movie"
            :data-index="index"
          />
    </template>
    
    <script>
...
      fetch ({ store }) {
        store.commit('storeVideos')
      },
      data () {
        return {
          prevpage: null,
          nextpage: null,
          currentPage: 1,
          pageNumbers: [],
          totalPages: 0,
          popularmovies: []
        }
      },
      watch: {
    
      },
      methods: {
        next () {
          this.currentPage += 1
        }
      }
    }
...
```

The array returns empty when I check the Vue Dev Tools.

Comment: `state.vidoes` is not the same as `state.videos` in the mutation

Comment: Corrected that, but its the same

Answer (score 0):

In `fetch()`, you're committing `storeVideos` without an argument, which would set `store.state.videos` to `undefined`, but I think you meant to dispatch the `getVideos` action:

```js
export default {
  fetch({ store }) {
    // BEFORE:
    store.commit('storeVideos')

    // AFTER:
    store.dispatch('getVideos')
  }
}
```

Also your action is incorrectly using its argument. The first argument is the Vuex context, which you could destructure `commit` from:

```js
export const actions = {
  // BEFORE:
  async getVideos (commit) {}  // FIXME: 1st arg is context

  // AFTER:
  async getVideos ({ commit }) {}
}
```

Comment: I totally agree that `async getVideos({commit})` is the cause